# Symfony 4 length validator translate error message

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, translation

I created a new project using the Symfony [website skeleton](https://github.com/symfony/website-skeleton) and created a new registration form, following the Symfony tutorial:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html#registrationformtype

Inside the twig.yaml I configured the bootstrap_4_layout:

```
twig:
  ...
  form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

In my RegistrationFormType class I'd like to translate the error messages in case the validation fails:

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
  'required'        => true,
  'type'            => PasswordType::class,
  'first_options'   => ['label' => 'register.password'],
  'second_options'  => ['label' => 'register.password_repeat'],
  'mapped'          => false,
  'constraints'     => [
    new Length([
      'min'        => 6,
      'max'        => 4096,
      'minMessage' => 'register.password_min_length'
    ]),
  ],
])
```

Unfortunately the text (register.password_min_length) is not translated. While te label 'register.password' and 'register.password_repeat' is translated like expected. After checking the bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig I noticed that the error message is not translated, so I tried to write a custom form theme:

```
{% form_theme registrationForm _self %}
{% block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <span class="{% if form is not rootform %}invalid-feedback{% else %}alert alert-danger{% endif %} d-block">
            {%- for error in errors -%}
                <span class="d-block">
                    <span class="form-error-icon badge badge-danger text-uppercase">{{ 'Error'|trans({}, 'validators') }}</span> <span class="form-error-message">{{ error.message|trans() }}</span>
                </span>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </span>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endblock form_errors %}
```

Now the error is translated but the {{ limit }} is not replaced with the actual value.

Does somebody had a similiar problem? Also within the Symfony Demo application I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: `trans` can get parameters, the first one is a map of values to replace. however, I don't know how to get them into the block, but it's probably part of the error object.

Comment: Where did you place the translation for `register.password_min_length`?

Comment: check if the translation exist first by typing : **php bin/console debug:translation lang**  replace lang by your language you want to check like fr, en

Comment: Use web profiler and check for translation domain

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI
The translation exists regarding the output.
Domain: messages
Id: register.password_min_length
And both language and fallback language are available

Comment: @xabbuh
I don't know what exactly you mean? The translation content is inside the XLIFF translation files. From the RegistrationFormType (which extends AbstractType) I do not have access to the translator itself

Comment: @Andrius
I noticed that the translation domain is **validators**

Comment: The self-posted solution, replacing the code with someone elses, entirely side steps the described issue. As such it is unlikely a verifiable answer will emerge to this specific issue rendering this question useless for future readers.

Comment: @Michael so use validators.en.yaml file for translations. Or change translation domain.
Then clear cache and should be okay

Answer (score -1):

I found a very useful project on Github:

https://github.com/giorgiopagnoni/symfony4-user

I can recommend this project to everyone who has similar problems like me. While checking the code everything get's more and more clear.